# .net core 3.0 + IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, iis-10

I have a simple controller

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class APIController : Controller
{
    ...
```

Therefore the route to the controller looks like `schema://host:port/api/actionName`. The thing is that everything works on my local machine, when running on kestrel. But when on the IIS I can't get a response other than `404 NotFound`. After some research, I found that if I change any character in the **controller** route to upper case, then everything works fine. I mean the next combinations are good:

1. `schema://host:port/apI/actionName`
2. `schema://host:port/aPi/actionName`
3. ...

Can't find out what is going on there. Any ideas, folks? I guess there is something silly, but I'm not smart enough to figure it out. Please, help

Comment: Is there a sub-code for that 404? (See: [The HTTP status code in IIS 7 and later versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0)). If that doesn't help, maybe *failed request tracing* will.

Comment: I suggest you could also check your IIS setting to make sure there is no other url rewrite rules is enabled to rewrite the api in the url.